# Change the value in a file for every specific byte - python

Tags: python

Right now, i'm reading from two files to take information from both files and combine them to one file..

The one file is with gps information.. which records a time every second, the other file is with data from a sensor recorded data every 5ms.. when I combine these two files, I take some data from the sensor, and the last bytes is with a timestamp (unix) from the sensor, AND here I have trouble, because the for a timestamp for each set of data, I have to take the time from the GPS and then plus with 5 ms, per dataset until I get the time from the GPS.

Right now my code write the same time for all 200 samples per second

```
piece_size_acc = 24 # 4 KiB
piece_size_gps = 8

with open(r"C:\PATH\00000003.acc.bin", "rb") as 
in_file_acc, open(r"C:\PATH\00000003.gps.bin", "rb") as in_file_gps:
    while True:
        in_file_gps.seek(tempNumOfBytesRead + 60)
        tempNumOfBytesRead = tempNumOfBytesRead + 60
        piece_gps = in_file_gps.read(piece_size_gps)
        tempNumOfBytesRead = tempNumOfBytesRead + 8
        if piece_gps == b"":
            output_file.close()
            break # end of file

        for i in range(0,200):
            piece_acc = in_file_acc.read(piece_size_acc)
            if piece_acc == b"":
                output_file.close()
                break # end of file
            output_file.write(piece_acc)
            output_file.write(piece_gps)
```

As u can see, the time, is 8 bytes long, between every 60-68bytes.

Can I plus the time with 5 millisecond when reading the bytes or should I get it out in text and the plus it?

Comment: Is your timestamp a 64 bit float encoded as bytes? You _could_ modify that directly, but it's pretty tricky! It would be _far_ safer to decode those bytes to a float, update the float and encode it back to bytes. You can use the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module for that.